# Answer callings outside the country domain

Tags: android, phone-call

I have a phone in Lebanon and it's working (my father can call and recharge it and .. because he is living inside the country)

> my problem is that I must receice a call from an important person and there no way to turn it to be over Internet.

```
Is that any solution or application to connect it outside over internet, that will probide me to forword my voice  (which is transfered over the net ) to that calling where that person hear my voice as I'm inside the country.
```

I'm so sorry if this question is too silly to be asked ... but I'm really confused and ally attempts of thinking has failed
I'm so grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My small solution that I reach until now is to deal with a person in that country to forward (redirect) any call from the mentioned number to my phone where I'm living ... I wish I would have it as an Android solution or using Skype ?